# Visual Studio 2013: Cannot update textbox with event handler

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am building an application using one of our vendors interfaces, which is required to keep a status message box updated.

I have some events which I have handled for testing using a Message box, but now I come to pass these messages to the display box I get nothing.

```
     Public Shared Sub PageAirHandler(ChannelNum As Integer, Index As Integer, ChannelType As CLARITYCOMLib.ChannelType, PageName As String) Handles Status1.AirStatusChanged
    MessageBox.Show(PageName)
    ControlPanel.AirStatusBox.Text = PageName
End Sub
```

The messagebox dutifully displays the PageName string, but the textbox does nothing... even if I replace the PageName String variable with "test"

```
ControlPanel.AirStatusBox.Text = "test"
```

I get no activity, no errors, nada. 
I have googled around, but every example I can find seems to show the same code.

I have recreated the textbox, tried buttons, labels and other objects with the same result.
Setting up a button click handler to update any of these works as expected.

Apologies if this is a noob blunder, but it's driving me nuts!

Comment: Standard VB.NET bug, the dreaded default instance of a Form class does not interact well with threaded code.  You are updating the wrong Form object, it isn't visible.  And you have to use BeginInvoke() to update UI from a worker thread.  Use the BackgroundWorker class so you don't have to shoot your foot like this, its ProgressChanged event runs on the right thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
Using dlg As New Form2
 dlg.ShowDialog()
End Using
```

Things like:

```
Form2.Show()
Form2.Show(Me)
Form2.ShowDialog()
Form2.ShowDialog(Me)
```

SHOUL BE AVOIDED but are possible, because Vb.net creates an implicit instance.
But the  problem is, this instance gets killed if
the call has be done.

There you can see that a class instance of a project does not interact correctly
in some cases.

As Hans Passant said, your call to set the textbox text 
targets the wrong instance.

Invoking to user controls is also possible with:

```
Me.invoke(sub()
TextBox1.Text = "Blabla"
End sub)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. but I'm a little baffled. I can see why using messagebox works, because it instantiates a new message box, so there's no confusion as to what object it is talking to, correct?